# Is there a way to test Google Play Billing trial without creating new account?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, google-play-console

I am currently facing a challenge while testing trials in my project (with Google Play Billing). To test a trial, I find myself having to go through the process of subscribing, paying, clearing data, reinstalling the app, and logging out of my account. This workflow is time-consuming, especially when conducting multiple tests.

Is there a more efficient way to test trials repeatedly without the need to create new Google Play accounts?

Any suggestions or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There are [three eligibility criteria](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/12154973#offer_eligibility) when you create offers, and one of them is 'developer determined.' This means that you, as a developer, can decide whether the offer can be used multiple times. Thus, it seems like a good option for testing.

Comment: Seems like it's useful way. Thanks, I'll try it